# Protecting PHP email form from injection?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I've heard of PHP forms being abused to send email from the person the form is supposed to send to. Is this an actual problem, and if so, how can it be fixed? Is it similar to preventing SQL injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [email injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection) security vulnerability. For example, if you're passing custom headers to the `mail()` function like in the following code sample, you're vulnerable:

```
<?php
$additional_headers = "Reply-To: {$_GET['user_email']}";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);
?>
```

Consider that a malicious user passes not only his email, but also additional headers like this:

```
<?php
//$_GET['user_email'] = "me@example.net";// this is what you expect
// this is what you're getting actually
$_GET['user_email'] = "me@example.net\r\nBcc: someone@example.net, ...";
?>
```

Then a malicious user would send a carbon copy of his supposedly SPAM-ridden message to a virtually unlimited list of users from your server under your name. One can even replace your message completely with his own this way by adding certain otherwise-safe MIME headers. You can only imagine to what consequences this can lead!

Solution is simple: don't trust anything you receive from a user, and filter/validate the received data.

Answer (score 0):

Any form is vulnerable if the input is not filtered properly. It doesn't matter if it's an email form, registration form, or even if it's backed by PHP.

For an email form, consider PHP's [filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) to properly sanitize the email.

A good rule of thumb is to remember FIFO: filter input, escape output.

Superglobals should pretty much be considered dirty and in need of filtering (input). The output escaping depends on the context: emailing to someone, inserting into a database, rendering in HTML -- All of which require different output filtering techniques.

Comment: Being picky but how does `FIFO: filter input, escape output.` Should it not be FIEO